# Go Back To Beginning Of Month On Input Date MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, function, date

Let's say that I have an input date of "2017-01-31" or "2017-02-28". I want to take this input date and make SQL change it to "2017-01-01" or "2017-02-01".

Is there a way to do this via MySQL functions in a query?

Comment: you does SQL have to change it? I assume there is something between the database call and user.

Answer (score 1):

Several ways to do that.  My preference is to use DATE_FORMAT to replace the day portion with constant `01`.

```
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2017-01-31','%Y-%m-01') + INTERVAL 0 DAY AS dt
```

There are lots of ways to skin that cat.

For example, we could subtract the integer number of days minus 1 ...

```
 SELECT '2017-01-31' + INTERVAL 1-DAY('2017-01-31') DAY
```

(With the second form, the date value needs to be supplied twice. With the first, we only need to supply the value one time. I think the first form is easier for a future reader to understand... pretty clear what the author is intending.)

Comment: Thanks man, amazing.

Comment: @Zeusftw: if you want the last day of the month, MySQL provides a `LAST_DAY()` function. Unfortunately, there is no `FIRST_DAY()` function.  In the first query, the `+ INTERVAL 0 DAY` isn't strictly necessary. But it does cause the string returned from `DATE_FORMAT` to be converted back into a `DATE`, which is what we would expect to be returned from a function that got us the "first day" of the month.

Comment: @Zeusftw , if you are happy with Spencer7593 's answer, please mark it as solved

Answer (score 0):

Use your date instead of my example:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('-',YEAR('2017-01-28'),MONTH('2017-01-28'),'01')
```